# Dom element infinitely incrementing

Tags: javascript

I'm in my first steps of creating an auto aim system for the enemy bot but I can't even seem to get him to shoot properly.

I create a div element, and move it in a direction. This happens every 4 seconds. I delete the div before the next one gets created. This works. But somehow it creates more and more elements over time and soon turns into a massive amount of divs all flying in the same direction.

** make the bullet here **

```
function makeBullet() {
    if (player.enemy) {

        if (player.enemyBullet.bulletInterval == true) {
            console.log("working");

            player.enemyBullet.bullet = document.createElement('div');
            player.enemyBullet.bullet.className = 'bullet';
            gameArea.appendChild(player.enemyBullet.bullet);

            player.enemyBullet.bullet.x = player.enemy.x;
            player.enemyBullet.bullet.y = player.enemy.y;

            player.enemyBullet.bullet.style.left = player.enemyBullet.bullet.x + 'px';
            player.enemyBullet.bullet.style.top = player.enemyBullet.bullet.y + 'px';
            player.enemyBullet.bulletInterval = false;
            setInterval(function () {
                player.enemyBullet.bulletInterval = true;
            }, 4000);
          }
        }
    }
```

** Move Bullet **

```
function moveBullet() {
        let bullets = document.querySelectorAll('.bullet');
        bullets.forEach(function (item) {
            item.x += 3;
            item.y -= 3;
            item.style.left = item.x + 'px';
            item.style.top = item.y + 'px';
            if(item.y < 200){
                item.parentElement.removeChild(item);
                player.enemyBullet.bullet = null;
            }

        })
    }
```

** invoked in request Animation function **

```
function playGame() {
    if (player.inplay) {
        moveBomb();
        moveBullet();
        makeBullet();

window.requestAnimationFrame(playGame);
    }
}
```

** Initiate interval boolean here **

```
let player = {
    enemyBullet: {
        bulletInterval: true
    }

}
```

** LINK TO JS FIDDLE FULL PROJECT ** (click here to see what's happening)

https://jsfiddle.net/mugs17/j7f12a0n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using setInterval like set timeout. However setInterval does not only execute one time. Once you've called setInterval the first time, calling it again makes a new different interval that also executes every 4 seconds.

So each time your function gets invoked its creating a new Interval which is why your div elements are increasing as time goes on

Instead wrap the entire create bullet code inside setInterval and make it execute only once by setting a boolean conditional and then immediately changing that conditional to false. Like this:

```
if (player.enemy) {
    if (player.enemyBullet.bulletInterval == true) {
        player.enemyBullet.bulletInterval = false;
        console.log("working");
        setInterval(function () {
            player.enemyBullet.bullet = document.createElement('div');
            player.enemyBullet.bullet.className = 'bullet';
            gameArea.appendChild(player.enemyBullet.bullet);

            player.enemyBullet.bullet.x = player.enemy.x;
            player.enemyBullet.bullet.y = player.enemy.y;

            player.enemyBullet.bullet.style.left = player.enemyBullet.bullet.x + 'px';
            player.enemyBullet.bullet.style.top = player.enemyBullet.bullet.y + 'px';
        }, 4000);
      }
   }
}
```